# How to add 2nd level parameter (property) to event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Im dispatching an event and need to set a parameter (property?) that is inside a parameter (nested?). Im providing an image of the event console log to explain better what I would like to do.

[image: SS from console log of the event]

For example how would I set the "accept" parameter to the event. I tried like this, but obviously i'm doing it wrong :D

```
var event = new Event ('change', {'currentTarget': {'accept': 'some-value'}});
```

EDIT: Trough additional digging i found out i have to use CustomEvent not Event, where i can add "details". But it still remains a question about how to add 2nd level property to the event. I tried with the following change but it's not working.

```
var event = new CustomEvent ('change', {'bubbles': true, detail: {'currentTarget': {'accept': 'some-value'}}});
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, you're not using jQuery's `Event` there. jQuery's `Event` is [`$.Event`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) (or `jQuery.Event` or `xyz.Event` where `xyz` is your identifier for jQuery, if you're using `noConflict`).

Comment: maybe `jQuery.Event('change', {'currentTarget': {'accept': 'some-value'}})`

Comment: My apoliges, I wasn't sure what to tag, web seemed a bit to general to tag. The event is being dispatched but the value of the parameter is not being set.

Comment: Have you tried to change `accept` using the dot operator? `currentTarger.accept = "something"` [THAT'S](https://imgur.com/a/iSt0w) what I mean.

Comment: @VTodorov I'm not sure how to add that to the event. As far as i managed to research, i'm getting close to a conclusion that it is not possible. I managed to add aditional properties with "detail" but that adds property "detail" with subproperties i define to the property tree. I'm looking to change a property that's by default there.

Comment: Try defining your object and changing its default values before the event.
Then pass the object to your event like `var event = new Event('change', myObj);`